# Can I change the loading order of some services in Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, services

Windows 10 Home.

I am trying to set priority to have my VPN, A/V, Spyware and Malware fire up before Windows connects to the internet.

1/ Visually I see this not happening, but it might be.

2/ Is there a way of seeing say a log file to alay my thought?

3/ Can I change the loading order of some services?

4/ Programs in my startup aren't a concern for me - but services are?

Comment: You may set starting type to Delayed and set separate starting timeout for each service for to achieve the order you need. But I'm not sure that all services in question can use this start type and that it is safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is little you can do about changing the startup order of your services.

A service can be setup to start manually, automatic and automatic delayed start.

You cannot control the order, but my experience tells me that windows system services that come preinstalled with windows start first unless they are set to delayed start or manual, then all programs start in order of installed, again with the exception for delayed start and manual.

When windows starts, programs can start in many ways.

First, before the user starts, the computer startup script is run. These are controlled through Group Policy and the run regkey in Local Computer. Programs started from this location are run as system because the user is not known yet. These programs can start services themselves, given that a service can run both from the user context and globally.

Next all user defined startup routines are fired.
The first is the logon script in a domain environment, then the registry Run in Users is started, Services that are run in the user context that are set to automatic will start here, then Group Policy is started unless they are configured to start with a delay, then shell:startup is started. At the point where either the Group Policy or shell:startup is executed, the user can already interact with the desktop. Depending on how quick the computer is, the user may or may not start programs themselves. Finally, services with delayed start will start together with delayed group policy.

If a computer boots very slowly, it may seem that services don't start, because the delayed start can take place minutes after boottime.

As you can see, what you want to do is ensure that whatever you want to start before the internet becomes available, is installed for all users, so they run as SYSTEM and can be started at Computer startup, rather than user login. This is how it normally is done, which is why AntiVirus/AntiMalware can ensure that it always runs before a virus can be executed by the user.

The same applies to Firewalls.

VPN is a different beast though. VPN usually is setup for a user and thus can't start on the computer during startup. There are hardware VPN solutions though, a router that can connect to another VPN. The connection is then always tunnelled through that VPN. This does require enterprise hardware or custom firmware.

Is there a log? Yes, the startup is logged in the EventLog, along with every other action that is taking place on your pc, but its not worth it to dive into it, because the above logic can be used to reason when something starts.

EDIT: Small note, Home editions do not have support for domains and group policy. You can disregard those mentions. If you ever upgrade to a Pro version of Windows, these become a possibility, so I kept them in the post for that reason.